# Referencing a SQL expression after aliasing it in UPDATE?

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

- `user` has a count of completed orders for that particular user.
- `order` has n-number of rows for a given `user_id`.

The number in the `user` table should match the number of rows in the `order` table for any given user.

A problem meant some of these are now mismatched so I am trying to make a query to update the `user` table to match the number of rows in the `order` table. So far I have a query like this:

```
UPDATE user
SET orders_completed = 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) oCount, o.user_id
    FROM order o
    WHERE o.completed_status = "complete"
    GROUP BY o.user_id) ordersComplete ordersComplete.oCount
WHERE ordersComplete.user_id = user.id;
```

However, the problem is when I try to alias the `SELECT` expression, then immediately use a column from it (`ordersComplete ordersComplete.oCount`)

Is it not possible to do this? And if not, is there any other way I could do this query?

Comment: What is your SQL database, such as MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc. ?

Comment: Why you are trying to alias the (SELECT ..) expression which is the right term in the SET .. = .. clause?

Comment: Inconsistent data is a typical result of storing values calculated from other table data.